# Implementing Abstract Properties in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

What's the best, most Pythonic, way to deal with abstract properties in Python? If I want to implement a base class which has a mixture of abstract properties, and concrete methods, I can do so similar to the following.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def property1(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def property2(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def property3(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_method(self):
        pass

    def concrete_method(self):
        return self.property1 + self.property2
```

However, when I then go to implement the inheriting class I need to implement each of those properties as getter method for a private property.

```
class Klass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, property1, property2, property3):
        self.__property1 = property1
        self.__property2 = property2
        self.__property3 = property3

    @property
    def property1(self):
        return self.__property1

    @property
    def property2(self):
        return self.__property2

    @property
    def property3(self):
        return self.__property3
```

Which seems both unnecessarily verbose, and makes the code more obscure than it needs to be.

I don't love the idea of implementing things concretely and raising a `NotImplementedError`if the inheriting class doesn't implement it's own version.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I know this comment does not change anything now, since this has a correct and accepted answer, but just for correctness, aren't you missing the `@property` decorator from `property1`, etc. in `BaseClass`? The `concrete_method` implementation suggests you really want to use these as attributes rather than method calls. But back in 2016, you probably could not stack/nest decorators...`@abstractproperty` was invented for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not required to implement properties as properties. All you need is for the *name* to exist *on the class*. So the following, using regular attributes, would work:

```
class Klass(BaseClass):
    property1 = None
    property2 = None
    property3 = None

    def __init__(self, property1, property2, property3):
        self.property1 = property1
        self.property2 = property2
        self.property3 = property3

    def abstract_method(self):
        # implementation for the abstract method
```

Note that there is a [`abstractproperty` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty) that'd better document that you want to use those names as simple values, not methods to call:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractproperty
    def property1(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def property2(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def property3(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod    
    def abstract_method(self):
        pass

    def concrete_method(self):
        return self.property1 + self.property2
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that the `abstractproperty` decorator existed, but it didn't make much sense to me to use it. This is a lot more readable.